# If a die is thrown repeatedly until each of the 6 faces appears at least once. What is the probability that you have to throw it 10 times?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know that the answer is 0.062 approximately, and that all the possible outcomes to throw ten times a die is 6^10.

Is it correct to solve it in this way:

((5 ^ 5) (5!) (10)) / (6 ^ 10)?

Comment: *Hint:*  Try calculating the probability that you do *not* see at least one of the faces within nine rolls.  Try calculating the probability that you do *not* see at least one of the faces within ten rolls.  Think inclusion-exclusion for these steps.  Then, think of the complement events and the difference between them and what that has to do with your problem.

Comment: But inclusion and exclusion would only be done for 9 and 10 rolls?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but yes... inclusion-exclusion will be involved in the answer my hint should be able to lead you towards.  It appears also in Bram28's answer, but perhaps in a different form... you could skip that step by using [stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) directly without appealing to inclusion-exclusion (*but the usual way to derive the formula for stirling numbers of 2nd kind is with inclusion-exclusion in the first place*)

Comment: how could it be done by a single combination or permutation, by way of having a general function for any number of times the die is thrown?

Comment: It cannot unless you allow stirling numbers of the second kind.  This is very simply not a problem that combinations and permutations are very useful for.

Comment: Does "you have to throw it 10 times" mean "you have to throw it 10 times and no more", i.e., by the 10th throw all six sides have come up? Or does it mean you have to throw it *at least* 10 times?

Comment: means that by the 10th throw all six sides have come up

Answer (score 2):

HINT

How many of those $6^{10}$ outcomes are ones where the first $9$ throws cover $5$ of the $6$ different faces, while the $10$-th gives the last face?

Comment: Is it correct to solve it in this way:

((5 ^ 5) (5!) (10)) / (6 ^ 10)?

Comment: @IsaíMartínez I see what you're trying to do' but no, it's not that simple since you need to take into account permutations. And once you do that, you need to take into account that sqapping two of the same numbers is not an additional permutation. So, you need to take into account how many you have of each of the $5$ faces among the first nine throws. In fact, that's where I would start!